# Google Assistant does not recognize the command for Smart Home Modes Trait

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I implement the Smart Home Modes Trait for Google Smart Home Action,but when I say "Ok, Google, What is the mode on D5s?" to query mode or "Ok, Google,set D5s to smart" to control mode, Google Assistant receives the command but **does not send the intent to my Fulfillment service**.How should I solve this problem?

Device: Google Nest Mini

action.devices.SYNC response is:

```json
{
    "payload":{
        "agentUserId":"uid-1",
        "devices":[
            {
                "traits":[
                    "action.devices.traits.StartStop",
                    "action.devices.traits.Modes"
                ],
                "willReportState":true,
                "name":{
                    "defaultNames":[
                        "D5s"
                    ],
                    "name":"D5s",
                    "nicknames":[
                        "D5s"
                    ]
                },
                "attributes":{
                    "availableModes":[
                        {
                            "settings":[
                                {
                                    "setting_name":"smart",
                                    "setting_values":[
                                        {
                                            "setting_synonym":[
                                                "smart"
                                            ],
                                            "lang":"en"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "setting_name":"mop",
                                    "setting_values":[
                                        {
                                            "setting_synonym":[
                                                "mop"
                                            ],
                                            "lang":"en"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "setting_name":"dock",
                                    "setting_values":[
                                        {
                                            "setting_synonym":[
                                                "dock"
                                            ],
                                            "lang":"en"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "setting_name":"spot",
                                    "setting_values":[
                                        {
                                            "setting_synonym":[
                                                "spot"
                                            ],
                                            "lang":"en"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "ordered":false,
                            "name":"mode",
                            "name_values":[
                                {
                                    "lang":"en",
                                    "name_synonym":[
                                        "mode"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "lang":"en",
                                    "name_synonym":[
                                        "Clean"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "lang":"en",
                                    "name_synonym":[
                                        "Mode"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "customData":{
                    "uid":"uid-1"
                },
                "id":"device-id1",
                "type":"action.devices.types.VACUUM",
                "deviceInfo":{
                    "swVersion":"sw1.0.0",
                    "model":"D5s Pro",
                    "manufacturer":"Smart ",
                    "hwVersion":"hw1.0.0"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "requestId":"11614522009820639979"
}
```

The mode control button already displayed on the Google Home App and that command is successfully working.Fulfillment service will receive the intent request.

Comment: Your Sync response looks perfectly fine. We tried to replicate it on our side and everything worked fine. Could you try creating a new project from scratch and make it work with Sync response you posted above.

Comment: I switched to other projects, no change in results, but with other Google Nest, it seems to work fine.